# what is the best way to migrate data from HBase to Cassandra for Janusgraph backend storage?

Tags: cassandra, hbase, janusgraph

I am using HBase as backend for Janusgraph. I have to migrate to Cassandra as backend. What is the best way to migrate the old data?

one way to go for it is to read data from Hbase and put into Cassandra using java code.

Answer (score 1):

Migrating data from JanusGraph is not well supported, so I would prefer myself to start from copies of the data that were made before ingesting it into JanusGraph. If that is not an option, your suggestion of using java code to read from one graph and ingest into the other comes first.

Naturally, you want to parallellize this, because millions of operations on a single thread and process take too long for being practical. Although JanusGraph supports OLAP traversals for reading vertices and edges in parallel, [JanusGraph OLAP has its own problems](https://www.experoinc.com/expero-resources/janusgraph-community-meetup) and you are probably better of segmenting the data using a mixed index in JanusGraph and have each process/thread read the segment assigned to it using an OLTP traversal.